# Gulp hangs after "Finishing"

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm new to node and developing in any sort of "proper" environment. I've installed gulp for my current project, along with mocha and a few other modules. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['js/**/*.js'])
        // eslint() attaches the lint output to the eslint property 
        // of the file object so it can be used by other modules. 
        .pipe(eslint())
        // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console. 
        // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs). 
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on 
        // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failOnError last. 
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('tests/test.js', {read: false})
        // gulp-mocha needs filepaths so you can't have any plugins before it 
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'list'}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['lint','test'], function () {
    // This will only run if the lint task is successful...
});
```

When I run 'gulp', it appears to complete all its tasks, but hangs. I have to ctrl+c to get back to the command prompt. How do I get it to finish properly?

Comment: You run any of the tasks by themselves (`gulp test`, `gulp lint`), do they hang? I've cut and pasted your code here and have no issue running it. Nothing hangs.

Comment: I will try this later, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apologies, folks! Turns out that this is addressed in the [gulp-mocha FAQ](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha#faq). To quote:

> **Test suite not exiting**
>
> If your test suite is not exiting it might be because you still have a lingering callback, most often caused by an open database
>   connection. You should close this connection or do the following:
>
> ```
> gulp.task('default', function () {
>     return gulp.src('test.js')
>         .pipe(mocha())
>         .once('error', function () {
>             process.exit(1);
>         })
>         .once('end', function () {
>             process.exit();
>         });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not running anything after `gulp-mocha`, the accepted solution will work for you. However, if you need to run tasks after `gulp-mocha` (for example running mocha tests before deploying a build) here's a solution that will prevent `gulp` from hanging indefinitely while still allowing tasks to run after `gulp-mocha`:

```
gulp.on('stop', () => { process.exit(0); });
gulp.on('err', () => { process.exit(1); });
```

This works because `gulp` [inherits](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L12) from [orchestrator](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator) which [emits the events](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratoronevent-cb) after all tasks have run to completion or error, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to mocha 4, I was able to resolve this by passing `--exit` to mocha.

See https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit for more information.

When using gulp-mocha, add the option as `exit: true` as in:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
  return gulp.src(['tests/**/*.spec.js'], {read: false})
  .pipe(mocha({ exit: true }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a return statement inside the gulp task. Or run the callback.

```
gulp.task('default', ['lint','test'], function (next) {
    // This will only run if the lint task is successful...
    next();
});
```

Comment: I've tried both the callback, and adding a return to no avail.